# How to know which page sent data in php

Tags: php

I was wondering wether it is possible
to know which page passed POST data
to an php script
example
a page http://example.com/abc.html send POST data to http://example.com/abc.php
so either a predefined or userdefined function shoud return example.com/abc.html by abc.php

Comment: I think you want `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by Simply using  Referer header. i.e $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

example :echo $_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'];
will print the link you want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Check the `Referer` header.  [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Note that this can be spoofed by the client easily, and sending the header isn't required.

Comment: +1, this was probably what he was looking for, regardless if it can be spoofed or not.

Comment: Thanks And can you please tell me how to protect from being spoofed..
and also how to spoof

Comment: @SubhankerChourasia, You can never prevent the client from spoofing any data.  However, if you are in control of the forms, you can create a page-specific CSRF token.  Basically, this is a random value you create when the page with the form is sent to the client.  It sits in a hidden form field.  When the form is submitted, you verify that the token you received is the one you sent to the client, and then you know what page it is on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hidden input variable that will be passed with POST, as an alternate to the header response:

```
<option type="hidden" name="mypage" value="abc">
```

Comment: Easily editable by anybody who knows what a page source is though

Comment: Same goes with the header :), but actually I'd like to +1 this as well. Mainly because you can put anything for this, and then on the backend it's easier to know what data you are handling. Example: `name=mypage&value=login`, then you can validate all the fields that belong to login.

Answer (score 1):

Hidden field makes sense but it seems easier to crate a variable on each page to name the this way you can use your php variable to return the correct information using if and else statements based On the page it's send from